# Using R to create a log-log scatter plot of the mean of two sets replicates

Tags: r, mean, scatter-plot, replicate

I have some RNA seq data for two different cell types (naive and Th1).

**How would I find the average of the two replicates of each cell type for each gene (the grouping variable) and then plot a log-log scatter graph of these data?**

My table looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Gene_name=c("Mrpl15", "Lypla1", "Tcea1"),
                 naive_A=c(5.21212, 6.62643, 5.74654),
                 naive_B=c(4.52376, 5.64459, 4.52153),
                 Th1_A=c(15.50650, 14.46030, 11.57770),
                 Th1_B=c(5.876490, 5.193010, 2.107200), stringsAsFactors=F)
df

  Gene_name naive_A naive_B   Th1_A   Th1_B
1    Mrpl15 5.21212 4.52376 15.5065 5.87649
2    Lypla1 6.62643 5.64459 14.4603 5.19301
3     Tcea1 5.74654 4.52153 11.5777 2.10720
```

If anyone can help, I'd be much obliged!! Thanks

Comment: It'd be helpful if you removed the domain-specific jargon and generalized this to a question about taking averages and plotting. Also, you'll get an answer more quickly if your question includes how to create the required sample data.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

```
df %>%
    gather(sample, expr, -Gene_name) %>%
    mutate(condition = gsub("_\\w$", "", sample)) %>%
    group_by(Gene_name, condition) %>%
    summarise(expr.mean = mean(expr)) %>%
    spread(condition, expr.mean) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = log10(naive), y = log10(Th1), label = Gene_name)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_text()
```

[image]

Explanation: Reshape data from wide to long, extract a `condition` column and average expression values for every gene for every condition. Then reshape data from long to wide, and plot the log10-transformed mean expression from `naive` vs. mean expression from `Th1` for every gene.

I've added gene labels just for illustration purposes. You can remove them by removing `+ geom_text()`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Gene_name   naive_A  naive_B    Th1_A    Th1_B
1    Mrpl15  5.21212 4.52376 15.50650 5.876490
2    Lypla1  6.62643 5.64459 14.46030 5.193010
3    Tcea1  5.74654 4.52153 11.57770 2.107200", header = T)
```